# View overriding using Deface

Tags: spree

I am trying to insert a text on show page of Spree's product page.

My app/overrides/show_new.html.erb as follows:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path  => "spree/products/show",
                 :insert_after => "[data-hook='product_show']",
                 :text          => "<p>This is overriding......</p>",
                 :name          => "show_new",
                 :disabled      => false)
```

But, the view is not overridden. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You must restart your app for the overrides to register first.

Otherwise, this seems correct (assuming your code is in app/overrides/something.rb)

Watch out if you are not on latest version, some views HTML are broken and it breaks deface.

https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/1056 (I ran into this issue last week)

Comment: You don't have to do this for the latest versions of Deface, and the views that are broken are now fixed in the latest version of Spree that's going through release candidate status now.

Comment: Thanks j15e! But in my case, it was the issue of file type. I used .erb template for overrides rather than .rb file.